# How do I checkbox.Checked using a variable of type "Control"?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to store the ID of CheckBox in a Control variable and then to test it if the CheckBox.Checked is true or false, here is my code:

```
    Control checkbox1 = FindControl(foo);
    if (checkbox1.Checked)
    {

    }
```

And I got this error:

> 'System.Web.UI.Control' does not contain a definition for 'Checked' and no extension method 'Checked' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.Control' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly

Comment: Please tell me where your checkbox is placed?Inside gridview or any?

Comment: You have to cast this control into checkbox control. like CheckBox checkbox1 = (CheckBox)FindControl(foo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use like this

```
CheckBox checkbox1 = FindControl(foo) as CheckBox;
if(checkbox1!=null)
{
    if (checkbox1.Checked)
    {
         //write your code here
    }
 }
```

Comment: @Tim: really? I prefer the opposite. Have you ever seen a case where the control was found but was not of the expected type?

Answer (score 1):

```
CheckBox checkbox1 = (CheckBox)FindControl(foo);
if (checkbox1.Checked)
{

}
```

You have to cast to the correct type. It doesn't happen by magic in .NET.

Answer (score 0):

If your control is placed inside gridview..Try looping through gridview and find the control and check it..

```
foreach (GridViewRow i in Gridview1.Rows)
{
    CheckBox checkbox1 = (CheckBox)FindControl(foo);
    if (checkbox1.Checked)
    {

    }
}
```

I am guessing Checkbox is inside gridview..You can do this in other cases also..